# Yocto unable to switch to sysvinit

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake, yocto-layer

I am building Yocto for Raspberry Pi. My configuration layer is like below.
I tried to override the init manager, however bitbake doesn't build `/sbin/init`.
How should I force bitbake to build `sysvinit`? I tried to copy `INIT_MANAGER` and few lines below to `poky/build/local.conf`. This didn't help either.

contents of `rpilinux-image.bb` file:

```
require recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb                                   
     
  IMAGE_INSTALL += "libstdc++ mtd-utils"    
  IMAGE_INSTALL += "openssh openssl openssh-sftp-server python3 python3-numpy"    
     
  MACHINE_FEATURES += " bluez5 bluetooth wifi alsa dhcp-client pulseaudio dbus bridge-utils"   
  MACHINE_FEATURES += " accessibility eglfs fontconfig gles2 linuxfb tslib sysvinit"   
     
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " wpa-supplicant iw module-init-tools dhcpcd"   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43430 linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43456"                                    
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " bcm2835-dev i2c-tools python3-smbus hostapd iptables"   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " dbus pulseaudio alsa-lib alsa-utils alsa-tools"   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " gstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-meta-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad "   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-python"   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server gstreamer1.0-vaapi"   
     
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " qtbase qtbase-dev qtbase-mkspecs qtbase-plugins qtbase-tools"                                                         
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " qt3d qt3d-dev qt3d-mkspecs qtcharts qtcharts-dev qtcharts-mkspecs"   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " qtconnectivity-dev qtconnectivity-mkspecs qtquickcontrols2 qtquickcontrols2-dev"   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " qtquickcontrols2-mkspecs qtdeclarative qtdeclarative-dev qtdeclarative-mkspecs"   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " qtgraphicaleffects qtgraphicaleffects-dev"   
     
  PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-qtmultimedia = " gstreamer alsa"   
     
  PACKAGECONFIG:append = " glfs gles2 linuxfb tslib sql-sqlite accessibility fontconfig"   
     
  # use sysvinit as the default init manager   
  INIT_MANAGER = "sysvinit"   
  DISTRO_FEATURES:append = "sysvinit"   
  DISTRO_FEATURES:remove = "systemd"   
  VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "sysvinit"   
  VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_dev_manager = "udev"   
  #DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "systemd"   
  VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "initscripts"   
     
     
  DEPENDS += " userland"   
     
  MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS += "\   
      linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43455 \                                                                                                  
      bluez-firmware-rpidistro-bcm4345c0-hcd \                                                                                             
      linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43456 \                                                                                                  
      bluez-firmware-rpidistro-bcm4345c5-hcd \                                                                                             
      linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43430 \                                                                                                  
      linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43455 \                                                                                                  
      bluez-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43430a1-hcd \                                                                                            
      bluez-firmware-rpidistro-bcm4345c0-hcd \                                                                                             
      "                                                                                                                                    
     
  RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE = " \   
      broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb \                                                                                                       
      broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb \                                                                                                       
      broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb \                                                                                                       
      broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-cm4s.dtb \                                                                                                      
      "                                                                                                                                    
     
  # We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " qt-simple-calc"
```

Configuration layer:

```
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── recipes-core
│   ├── base-files
│   │   ├── base-files
│   │   │   └── fstab
│   │   └── base-files_%.bbappend
│   ├── image
│   │   └── qt5-my-image.bb
│   └── init-ifupdown
│       ├── init-ifupdown
│       │   └── interfaces
│       └── init-ifupdown_%.bbappend
└── recipes-rpilinux
    └── images
        └── rpilinux-image.bb
```

Contents of `/sbin` directory:

```
sh-5.2# cd /sbin/
sh-5.2# ls
agetty               fsck.util-linux      modprobe
badblocks            fstrim               modprobe.kmod
blkid                fstrim.util-linux    nologin
blkid.util-linux     getty                nologin.shadow
blockdev             hwclock              nologin.util-linux
blockdev.util-linux  hwclock.util-linux   pivot_root
bridge               insmod               pivot_root.util-linux
cfdisk               insmod.kmod          populate-extfs.sh
ctrlaltdel           ip                   rmmod
debugfs              ip.iproute2          rmmod.kmod
depmod               ldconfig             rtmon
depmod.kmod          logsave              sulogin
dhcpcd               losetup              sulogin.util-linux
dumpe2fs             losetup.util-linux   swapoff
e2freefrag           lsmod                swapoff.util-linux
e2fsck               mdadm                swapon
e2image              mdmon                swapon.util-linux
e2mmpstatus          mke2fs               switch_root
e2undo               mke2fs.e2fsprogs     switch_root.util-linux
e4crypt              mkfs.ext2            sysctl
e4defrag             mkfs.ext2.e2fsprogs  sysctl.procps
fdisk                mkfs.ext3            udevadm
fdisk.util-linux     mkfs.ext4            udevd
filefrag             mklost+found         vigr
fsck                 mkswap               vigr.shadow
fsck.ext2            mkswap.util-linux    vipw
fsck.ext3            modinfo              vipw.shadow
fsck.ext4            modinfo.kmod
```

Kernel boot log:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.1.54-v8 (oe-user@oe-host) (aarch64-poky-linux-gcc (GCC) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.40.0.20230703) #1 S3
[    0.000000] random: crng init done
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x000000002ac00000, size 64 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003b3fffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA32: 19456 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA32: 16384 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 29 pages/cpu s80104 r8192 d30488 u118784
[    0.000000] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-v2
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-v3a
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-v4
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Spectre-BHB
[    0.000000] CPU features: kernel page table isolation forced ON by KASLR
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Kernel page table isolation (KPTI)
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 1742098
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM errata 1165522, 1319367, or 1530923
[    0.000000] alternatives: applying boot alternatives
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 996912
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=0 bcm2708_fb.fbheit
[    0.000000] Kernel parameter elevator= does not have any effect anymore.
[    0.000000] Please use sysfs to set IO scheduler for individual devices.
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:all(zero), heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: area num 4.
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x0000000037400000-0x000000003b400000] (64MB)
[    0.000000] Memory: 3813396K/4050944K available (13056K kernel code, 2174K rwdata, 4412K rodata, 4352K init, 1093K bss, 172012K reserve)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 42247 entries in 166 pages
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocated 166 pages with 4 groups
[    0.000000] trace event string verifier disabled
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
[    0.000000]  Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] Root IRQ handler: gic_handle_irq
[    0.000000] GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
[    0.000000] rcu: srcu_init: Setting srcu_struct sizes based on contention.
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 54.00MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0xc743ce346, max_idle_ns: 440795203123 ns
[    0.000001] sched_clock: 56 bits at 54MHz, resolution 18ns, wraps every 4398046511102ns
[    0.000310] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000381] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 108.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=216000)
[    0.000406] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000534] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.000737] Mount-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.000795] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.002061] cgroup: Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.004179] cblist_init_generic: Setting adjustable number of callback queues.
[    0.004192] cblist_init_generic: Setting shift to 2 and lim to 1.
[    0.004367] cblist_init_generic: Setting adjustable number of callback queues.
[    0.004377] cblist_init_generic: Setting shift to 2 and lim to 1.
[    0.004542] cblist_init_generic: Setting adjustable number of callback queues.
[    0.004553] cblist_init_generic: Setting shift to 2 and lim to 1.
[    0.004973] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.004984] rcu:     Max phase no-delay instances is 1000.
[    0.006310] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.006821] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.007888] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU1
[    0.008045] CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000001 [0x410fd083]
[    0.009176] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU2
[    0.009296] CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000002 [0x410fd083]
[    0.010416] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU3
[    0.010538] CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000003 [0x410fd083]
[    0.010735] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.010750] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated.
[    0.010761] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
[    0.010770] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL1 Support
[    0.010782] CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
[    0.010914] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL2
[    0.010935] alternatives: applying system-wide alternatives
[    0.012856] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.024912] Enabled cp15_barrier support
[    0.024944] Enabled setend support
[    0.025304] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.025338] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.027024] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.027884] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.028660] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.031935] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
[    0.032258] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
[    0.033190] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
[    0.033281] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.033549] audit: type=2000 audit(0.032:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.034132] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.034215] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.034462] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.034652] ASID allocator initialised with 32768 entries
[    0.034821] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.046289] bcm2835-mbox fe00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.060388] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2023-10-17T15:39:16, variant start
[    0.064402] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 30f0c5e4d076da3ab4f341d88e7d505760b93ad7
[    0.079059] KASLR enabled
[    0.110793] bcm2835-dma fe007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.116473] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.116723] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.116777] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.116842] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.117174] usb_phy_generic phy: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.117398] usb_phy_generic phy: dummy supplies not allowed for exclusive requests
[    0.117768] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.117779] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.117803] PTP clock support registered
[    0.118060] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.118948] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.119523] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.120161] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.120582] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.120775] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.120937] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.130293] NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
[    0.130801] IP idents hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.135725] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 2048 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.135781] Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.135808] TCP established hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.135993] TCP bind hash table entries: 32768 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.136983] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 32768 bind 32768)
[    0.137459] MPTCP token hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 98304 bytes, linear)
[    0.137667] UDP hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.137729] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.137994] NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family
[    0.138787] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.138801] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.138811] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.138820] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.138843] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.141333] hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_cortex_a72 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.141704] kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 44 bits
[    0.143123] kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ9
[    0.143350] kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully
[    1.207964] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.208423] workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=20 bucket_order=0
[    1.216036] zbud: loaded
[    1.218853] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.218887] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.218897] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.219031] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.219045] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.220721] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.220737] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.220821] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 246)
[    1.221092] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.221107] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.231820] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
[    1.231860] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   No bus range found for /scb/pcie@7d500000, using [bus 00-ff]
[    1.231947] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:      MEM 0x0600000000..0x063fffffff -> 0x00c0000000
[    1.232032] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   IB MEM 0x0000000000..0x00ffffffff -> 0x0400000000
[    1.233062] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    1.233080] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    1.233097] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x63fffffff] (bus address [0xc0000000-0xffffffff])
[    1.233170] pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
[    1.233425] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.237182] pci 0000:00:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
[    1.237440] pci_bus 0000:01: supply vpcie3v3 not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.237636] pci_bus 0000:01: supply vpcie3v3aux not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.237736] pci_bus 0000:01: supply vpcie12v not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.345633] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 (SSC)
[    1.345799] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    1.345924] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    1.346402] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.355643] pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: [bus 01-ff] end is updated to 01
[    1.355686] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.355709] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
[    1.355751] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    1.355772] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.356764] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Unable to determine number of FBs. Disabling driver.
[    1.356779] bcm2708_fb: probe of soc:fb failed with error -2
[    1.364140] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.367051] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.367569] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    1.369070] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe200000
[    1.384401] brd: module loaded
[    1.393087] loop: module loaded
[    1.393774] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.398950] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
[    1.495677] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
[    1.496792] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    1.496860] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.496924] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.542827] pci 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.542998] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.543028] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.543789] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0b00040000000890
[    1.544945] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.544964] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.544988] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.545346] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.01
[    1.545365] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.545378] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.545391] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.54-v8 xhci-hcd
[    1.545402] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.546133] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.546197] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.547140] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.01
[    1.547158] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.547172] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.547184] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.54-v8 xhci-hcd
[    1.547196] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.547933] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.548024] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.549701] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.550539] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.550630] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.550834] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.557173] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.557189] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.557750] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.562201] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.562409] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.562517] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.562524] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.569375] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
[    1.569442] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.570159] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.570212] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.570730] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    1.570737] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
[    1.578650] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    1.579073] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    1.579164] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA1 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 35, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.579302] serial serial0: tty port ttyAMA1 registered
[    1.587063] bcm2835-aux-uart fe215040.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    1.587579] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.587639] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xfe215040 (irq = 36, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
[    1.811523] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.811704] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.042639] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    2.057708] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    2.062717] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.069694] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    2.072552] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    2.073938] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.077864] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    2.082158] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.085820] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    2.115331] of_cfs_init
[    2.153443] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.mmc [fe340000.mmc] using ADMA
[    2.155615] of_cfs_init: OK
[    2.232681] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    2.234319] ALSA device list:
[    2.352073] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address 59b4
[    2.357238]   No soundcards found.
[    3.161304] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 SD32G 29.1 GiB 
[    3.167858]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    3.170943] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 SD32G 29.1 GiB
[    3.178750] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[    3.187486] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    3.195235] devtmpfs: mounted
[    3.202671] Freeing unused kernel memory: 4352K
[    3.207385] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    3.215864] Run /etc/init as init process
[    3.223940] Run /bin/init as init process
[    3.229577] Run /bin/sh as init process
sh: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell
sh-5.2#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the following in my conf file:

`IMAGE_INSTALL += " packagegroup-core-boot"`